# Emacs, binding "C-c s" key to "<menu>" key

Tags: emacs, binding, prefix, cscope

How to bind "C-c s" to "< menu >" key, so that I can use Cscope in emacs easily? My aim is to replace C-c s prefix with menu key.

Instead of pressing "C-c s g", I have to press "< menu > g" and 
Instead of pressing "C-c s =", I have to press "< menu > =" and for remaining cscope bindings.

edit 1:

Well, I have already done this by binding each key separately to cscope functions. I was searching for more generic and smaller solution.

I have done it like this,

```
(define-key global-map [(menu) (s)] 'cscope-find-this-symbol)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (d)] 'cscope-find-global-definition)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (g)] 'cscope-find-global-definition)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (G)] 'cscope-find-global-definition-no-prompting)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (=)] 'cscope-find-assignments-to-this-symbol)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (c)] 'cscope-find-functions-calling-this-function)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (C)] 'cscope-find-called-functions)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (t)] 'cscope-find-this-text-string)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (e)] 'cscope-find-egrep-pattern)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (f)] 'cscope-find-this-file)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (i)] 'cscope-find-files-including-file)
;; --- (The '---' indicates that this line corresponds to a menu separator.)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (b)] 'cscope-display-buffer)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (B)] 'cscope-display-buffer-toggle)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (n)] 'cscope-history-forward-line-current-result)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (N)] 'cscope-history-forward-file-current-result)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (p)] 'cscope-history-backward-line-current-result)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (P)] 'cscope-history-backward-file-current-result)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (u)] 'cscope-pop-mark)
;; ---
(define-key global-map [(menu) (a)] 'cscope-set-initial-directory)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (A)] 'cscope-unset-initial-directory)
;; ---
(define-key global-map [(menu) (L)] 'cscope-create-list-of-files-to-index)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (I)] 'cscope-index-files)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (E)] 'cscope-edit-list-of-files-to-index)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (W)] 'cscope-tell-user-about-directory)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (S)] 'cscope-tell-user-about-directory)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (T)] 'cscope-tell-user-about-directory)
(define-key global-map [(menu) (D)] 'cscope-dired-directory)
```

Comment: Did you try customizing `cscope-keymap-prefix`

Comment: thanks  @jenesaisquoi! I was able to do by adding following line                               **(define-key cscope-minor-mode-keymap (kbd "<menu>") (lookup-key cscope-minor-mode-keymap (kbd "C-c s")))**